# sed one-liner to delete any line that does not contain lowercase letters

Tags: sed, awk

So, basically

THIS LINE WOULD BE DELETED

and

(THIS LINE WOULD ALSO BE DELETED)

but

Indeed, THIS LINE WOULD NOT

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quite a few ways.  Think negatively:

```
sed '/[a-z]/!d'    # !x runs x if the pattern doesn't match
grep -v '[a-z]'    # -v means print if the regexp doesn't match
awk '!/[a-z]/'     # !expr negates expr
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
sed '/[a-z]/!d' file
```